# There is a way to parse from smarty?

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

folks! At php I have such code:

```
'homeSize' => Image::getSize('home')))
```

So, there is a way to parse it from smarty?

For example:

```
'largeSize' => Image::getSize('large')
```

Comment: So, I have done it myself - to parse from Smarty: {assign var='largeSize' value=Image::getSize('large')}

Comment: You can post this as a response and mark it as "answered"

Answer (score 1):

Using the modifier "getimagesize" you can get all required info about an image.
I wrote an example on how to split the result in to separate variables here:
http://www.i-do-this.com/blog/49/Getting-the-image-dimensions-in-smarty

Comment: In such case, you may consider including code snippet in your answer. Linking to your own pages can be perceived as self-promotion and lead to downvote. See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. And welcome on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks for the warning FabienAnre! I'll make sure to include code snippets in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I have done it myself - to parse from Smarty: {assign var='largeSize' value=Image::getSize('large')}